# Implementing NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have fairly large amount of data which I would like to partition into the custom sections,  for sections based on some keypath and some other sections on some other conditions. So I came up with idea to subclass `NSFetchedResultsController`. This subclass of `NSFetchedResultsController` should provide the flexibility of returning the sections in its method `-(NSArray*)sections` which returns an array of `id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>`. If I could implement by own class that conforms to the protocol and then pass the custom array of the objects in sections method of `fetchedResultsController`, I think I could accomplish my task.

Is there a way to implement `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` in your own class and then return the custom array of such object in the `fetchedResultsController` subclass? Or is there some library to accomplish this?

Edit

Let me describe what I am trying to achieve. I have Contacts model as NSManagedObject subclass. This entity has a attribute called state which can be unknown, known and unidentified. Now, I want these contacts to be sectioned in such a way that all the unknown contact appear in a single section, also the unidentified contacts should be in another different section. Now, all other known contacts should be in the different sections according to the name of contact. How can this be done ?

My table view should be populated as;

```
Unknown Contacts (sorted into a single section according to date )
  - 
  -
Known Contacts(A)(known contacts sorted into different sections according to the name)
  -
  -
Known Contacts(B)
  -
  -
  -
Known Contacts(C)
  -
  -
  -
  -
  -
  -
Known Contacts(Z)
 -
UnIdentified Contacts(sorted into a single section with first name)
  -
  -
  -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` already implements this.

```
NSArray* sectionsArray = self.fetchedResultsController.sections;
```

To implement the special sections follow the principles in the Apple sample code [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html). The pattern is as follows:

- Create a new transient attribute `sectionIdentifier`. Like in the sample code, also include the `primitiveSectionIdentifier` attribute in your managed object subclass. This is the attribute that you use for `sectionNameKeyPath` in your FRC.
- Devise a scheme that sorts correctly. Put all the sorting and computing logic into the class implementation file's custom getter for `sectionIdentifier`. For example you could simply use two characters that sort *before* the capital letter "A" which presumably would be the first of your regular section headers. You could also make it into a number, say 1 and 2 for your first two sections, and 3+ for the first letters in the alphabet.
- Decode your scheme in `titleForHeaderInSection` to display the desired content.

I recently did this for a client who had a non-standard coding scheme for a large list of contacts indicating some marketing segmentation. The data for the section identifier was also pulled from several different attributes.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I need to customize the sections and I feel it would be easier if I could implement this in my own class and then return the array of the class in sections method of fetchedresultscontroller subclass.

Comment: Tell us more about the customization you want to do. I usually handle these cases with a simple `sectionIdentifier` transient property that can be very flexible.

Comment: I dont understand it, I have also made some changes in the question to reflect my table population. Could you please elaborate with respect to this.

Comment: Just follow what I have written. Use the number scheme and make the last category the highest number (larger than the number of all letters of the alphabet), e.g. 100. You can manage just displaying the first name in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.